# Bone Constraints and Drivers not exporting correctly on FBX

Tags: animation, armature, export, constraints, .fbx

I'm currently trying to export my armature + mesh to Unity, however, the animations did not seem to export correctly (FBX).

The armature's bone constraints and driver seemed to only be refreshed 1-2 frames after the beginning of each animations, resulting in a **snappy/jittery motion**, the animation then **plays fine afterwards**. The animation too plays fine in Blender preview when the constraints and drivers are fully refreshed and working as intended.

After looking around the internet for the issues, it seems cyclic dependencies could be the issue but after looking around, I've made sure that there are **no cyclic dependencies present in my armature**. And that the only other solution I found was to tick the **"Extra Object Update"** and **"Extra Data Update"** in the Armature Properties.

[image: The "Solution" in 2.79 but not in any version afterwards.]

However, the solution mentioned above is only available in **version 2.79**, and not present in any version afterwards, I am currently on **version 3.1**.

I am unfortunately also unable to link my blend file, but I am confident there is nothing wrong on my end.

Any advice/solution is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you can apply it in your case, but I generally use the Bake Animation function, in order to bake all the deforming bones visual keying animations, and export a simplified rig, deforming bones only (and maybe one root bone), without any constraint or driver, whoose action gets applied during the baking process.

Comment: We've thought about this method before but it felt a bit destructive and the workflow won't really work well with our current pipeline.

Still, thanks for the advice!